# Declaration issue with using curry in point-free style in Haskell

Tags: haskell, declaration, pointfree

I am trying to understand the concept of point-free style. I made a function try to add two values using `uncurry`.

```
add = (+) . uncurry
```

and the result complains:

```
No instance for (Num ((a0, b0) -> c0))
  arising from a use of `+'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Num ((a0, b0) -> c0))
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(+)'
In the expression: (+) . uncurry
In an equation for `add': add = (+) . uncurry
```

Is this a declaration problem? I tried `add :: (Int, Int) -> Int`, it is does not work as well.

Comment: Try typing in GHCi `:t (+)`, `:t uncurry`, `:t ((+).uncurry)` and `:t (uncurry.(+))`. Then `:t (uncurry +)`.

Comment: The answers will tell you what you need to do to solve your problem, but I’m more interested in your reasoning for using `(+) . uncurry`. Did you expect `uncurry` to take a pair and return two values, passing those values along to `(+)`?

Comment: I think I got confused of if (+) to be considered as an function. I think it should be passed as an argument to uncurry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass `(+)` to `uncurry`:

```
add :: (Int, Int) -> Int
add = uncurry (+)
```

This is because `uncurry` is a function that takes a binary function and returns an unary function:

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
```

Your binary function is `(+)` which takes two `Num`s and sums them up. Therefore `uncurry (+)` will transform `(+)` into:

```
(Num, Num) -> Num
```

which is then restricted by the `add` type signature to:

```
(Int, Int) -> Int
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `a -> b -> c` is a unary function which takes a value of type `a` and returns value of type `b -> c`.

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you :). I thought (+) is a function which should be an argument.